# How to export 2 datasets in to excel “Sheet1”and another set of 2 datasets into “Sheet2” using SAS

Tags: excel, sas, dataset, export

Good Morning!
I want to export a few dataset's to excel using SAS, But I have a few challenges here. Both datasets are unique and which we cannot merge or append.

There are 2 programs that create 2 dataset's each, however, I want to export program1 output datasets(2 datasets) to excel sheet1 and Program2 output dataset'(2 datasets) to Excel sheet2.

I tried using Proc print but it didn't work

```
    ods excel file="&OUTFILE." options(sheet_interval="none"  sheet_name="sheet1");

TITLE 'CLOSED_SR_VOLUMES_BY_PERCENT';
proc print data=CLOSED_SR_VOLUMES_BY_PERCENT;
run;
TITLE 'CLOSED_SR_VOLUMES_BY_VOLUME';
proc print data=CLOSED_SR_VOLUMES_BY_MONTH;
run;


ods excel options(sheet_interval="none" sheet_name="sheet2");
TITLE 'ACTIVE_SR_VOLUMES_BY_VOLUME';
proc print data=SR_VOLUMES_BY_MONTH;
run;
TITLE 'ACTIVE_SR_VOLUMES_BY_PERCENT';
proc print data=SR_VOLUMES_BY_PERCENT;
run;
ods excel close;
```

I am not getting any error but all the datasets are exporting it to one excel sheet instead 2 datasets into sheet1 and another 2 datasets into Sheet2.

Please let me know if there any way to this...

Comment: Why tag Excel - this is SAS programming...

Comment: What version of SAS do you have? This was a known bug in 9.4M2 but was fixed in 9.4M3 afaik. There is a known workaround though, but it depends on your version.

Comment: @SolarMike So that people can search for questions that contain both tags?

Comment: @RobertPenridge so looking for excel based questions to answer, people get that and it’s not relevant...

Comment: @SolarMike You can easily exclude questions that contain both the `sas` and `excel` tags using this search query: `[excel] -[sas]`.  Alternatively you can read the title of the question (this one explicitly states 'using SAS' as part of the title), or look at the tags before clicking into the question.  Of the 195k questions on SO that contain an `excel` tag, only 1k of them also contain a `sas` tag.  So ignoring one question out of every 200 shouldn't be too much of an ordeal regardless.  Personally, I still think the upside of listing both tags outweighs the downsides.

Answer (score 1):

At first look seems like a [known ods bug](https://communities.sas.com/t5/ODS-and-Base-Reporting/ODS-excel-amp-multiple-sheets/m-p/261953#U261953), so u can try to investigate it.
As an easier solution, i would suggest to use DATA STEP to export data using LIBNAME :

```
libname xllib xlsx "&outpath/filename.xlsx";
data xllib.sometabname;
 set sashelp.cars;
 run;
libname myxl clear;
```

This code extracts data from `sashelp.cars` and writes it to the `filename` workbook on a tab named `sometabname`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the most recent maintenance release of SAS, you can do this with a small modification:

```
   ods excel file="&OUTFILE." options(sheet_interval='none' sheet_name="sheet1");

TITLE 'CLOSED_SR_VOLUMES_BY_PERCENT';
proc print data=sashelp.class;
run;
TITLE 'CLOSED_SR_VOLUMES_BY_VOLUME';
proc print data=sashelp.class;
run;


ods excel options(sheet_interval='now' sheet_name="sheet2");
TITLE 'ACTIVE_SR_VOLUMES_BY_VOLUME';
proc print data=sashelp.class;
run;
TITLE 'ACTIVE_SR_VOLUMES_BY_PERCENT';
proc print data=sashelp.class;
run;
ods excel close;
```

Note I add the 'now' instead of 'none' in the second one.  That seems to be necessary to force a sheet change.

This doesn't work with early versions of ODS EXCEL, but either in 9.4 TSM3 or TSM4 I believe it was fixed.  I have TSM6 and can confirm it works on that.